# MFC CSocket SendTo return error code 10038

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I have a multicast server socket. When I realize operation SendTo of MFC CSocket, he return to me an error code 10038. That means `"WSAENOTSOCK   The descriptor is not a socket."`

So someone can tell me how to fix this problem.

This is my code for creating the server socket

```
Create(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,NULL);
    Bind(12234,"225.6.7.8");
    int optVal = 10;
    int i = SetSockOpt(IP_MULTICAST_TTL,(void*)&optVal,sizeof(int));
```

and this is the operation to send a header to client

```
int result = this->SendTo(header, header.GetLength(),12234,"225.6.7.8");
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to include some code here.

Comment: Did you check return codes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to Bind at all, since you are using Datagrams and not streams.